Stub MongoDB calls with Sinon
I am trying test my routes but I can't stub my repository function, I want to stub the function that in the repository that calls the database.
This is my test file:
import { expect } from "chai";
import sinon from "sinon";
import request from "supertest";
import app from "../src/app.js";

describe("GET /users", () => {
  let fetchStub;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchStub = sinon.stub(
      import("../src/repository/product.repository.js"),
      "fetch"
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it("should return One Product", async () => {
    const product = {
      _id: new ObjectId(),
      code: 123456,
      url: "https://example.com",
      imported_t: "2020-02-07T16:00:00Z",
    };
    fetchStub.resolves(product);

    const res = await request(app)
      .get(`/products/findOne/${product.code}`)
      .set("x-api-key", "my-api-key");

    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
  });

My repository
import db from "../db/db.js";

const collection = db.collection("products");

export const fetch = async (code) => {
  return await collection.findOne({ code: parseInt(code) });
};


My controller
import {
  fetch
} from "../repository/product.repository.js";


export const getProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { code } = req.params;
    const product = await fetch(code);
    if (!product) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Product not found" });
    }

    res.status(200).json(product);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};


and I am getting this error when I ran the test
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property fetch

What can I try next?

The problem was the way I was exporting my repository functions, I use:
export default {
  fetch,
};

Instead
export const fetch = () => {}

and in the test file I did this way to stub my repository function
import repository from "../src/repository/product.repository.js";

fetchStub = sinon.stub(repository, "fetch");

and now the Sinon can identify my fetch function, of course I had to refactor my controller too

The really strange thing here is that you are able to modify an export IMHO. Those are usually immutable/cannot be assigned to, unless you employ some kind of transpilation or use custom software like jdalton's esm to make the namespace mutable. What is going here to make this possible? You are esentially doing repository.fetch = sinon.stub(); That should usually throw an error.
